# Discord.py | Can I have space in command name?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I wanted to ask can I have space in a command name for my discord.py bot like the command would be `-slowmode off`

Comment: What have you tried to implement this already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using [`ext.commands`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/index.html), then as far as I know you can't have command names with spaces in them. However, you can have:

- commands [with parameters](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#parameters) (which is what you probably want in this case), or
- command [groups](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html#parameters) which allow making a command with a multiword prefix.

For the first case, you can do:

```py
@bot.command()
async def slowmode(ctx, arg):
    # do something...
    await ctx.send('slowmode set to ' + str(arg))
```

...and invoke it with `-slowmode off` or `-slowmode hello`.

For the second case:

```py
@bot.group(invoke_without_command=True)
async def slowmode(ctx):
    await ctx.send('You must provide a subcommand, for example `-slowmode on` or `-slowmode off`; see `-help` for more')

@slowmode.command(name='on')
async def slowmode_enable(ctx):
    # do something...
    await ctx.send('slowmode is set to on')

@slowmode.command(name='off')
async def slowmode_disable(ctx):
    # do something...
    await ctx.send('slowmode is set to off')
```

...and invoking `-slowmode` will show the error message, `-slowmode on` or `-slowmode off` will run the appropriate command, and `-slowmode hello` will cause a [`CommandNotFound` exception](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.CommandNotFound).

Answer (score 1):

Since it looks like you want to add a parameter, you would do it like this:

```
@bot.command()
async def slowmode(ctx, mode):
    if mode.lower() == "off":
        # do something
```

Which would be invoked as `-slowmode off` or `-slowmode any`

This is probably the best way

Comment: wait lemme try it

Comment: Mark the answer as the right one :> welcome to Stack Overflow

Comment: this one works too but the one i marked as the answer is a better way